# List Remote RDS Sessions with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

Tried to follow

- https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/use-powershell-list-rds-sessions
- https://powershelladministrator.com/2015/12/01/get-logged-on-users-and-sessions/

But failed:

[image]

So how to use PowerShell to List Remote RDS Sessions?

**UPDATE:**

Tried to use `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogonSession -Filter "LogonType = 10"`, but it *"doesnt pull usernames or SSIDs of any domain user accounts, only local services and sessions"*:

[image]

Comment: `RemoteDesktop` is going to be a feature of PowerShell 5.1 only.  You don't mention what OS you are running.  Have you installed the optional Windows Feature`Remote-Desktop-Services`?

Comment: @Ramhound, Windows 10, and as you can see, I also have PowerShell 7. So how to install and make use of the optional Windows FeatureRemote-Desktop-Services?

Comment: You install Remote-Desktop-Services from the optional windows feature GUI.  You can also run ` Install-WindowsFeature Remote-Desktop-Services` in an elevated PowerShell prompt.  I cannot infer what version of Windows you are running based on your screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try connecting to the remote server first, and importing the module there:

```
Enter-PSSession -Computername 'RD-Server01'
Import-Module RemoteDesktop
```

You can install the `RemoteDesktop` module on your local machine too:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Rsat.RemoteDesktop.Services.Tools* | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

Comment: The reason that I need to list Remote RDS Sessions is because it's constantly occupied, thus I need a way to know when it is OK "connecting to the remote server" in the first place.

Comment: But thanks for answering how to make use of the `Import-Module RemoteDesktop`. Since nobody else answered this question for so long, I'll accept yours.

Comment: @xpt You should be able to use powershell remoting (PSSession commands) whether the server is busy or not. If you only want to quickly find out how many sessions are active, I recommend `quser /server:$name`. It's not powershell, so it doesn't return useful objects for scripts, but it's a great tool. Plus, you can then use `logoff $ID /server:$name`

Comment: Oh, that's very valuable supplementary. Would you like to put those in the answer as well pls?